# Truffle deploy compiles contracts but doesnt migrate to network

Tags: ubuntu, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle

As shown below, when running truffle deploy contracts are being compiled in /build directory, but they are never migrated to the specified network.

There are NO LOGS at all for truffle deploy to allow debugging of the issue. even while running --versbose-rpc, it shows nothing that makes sense.

I have enough Eth and blockchain is running fine.

Truffle.js config
[image: Truffle Config]

Eth Amount
[image: Eth Amount]

Truffle Deploy --network NetworkName Result
[image: Deploy Result]

Comment: Does it work with `truffle migrate`?

Comment: Have you tried with Truffle v4?

Comment: @nikosfotiadis no, it fails silently as if nothing was executed.

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin yes it's working on v4 but my solidity contracts are written in solc 0.5.0 which forces truffle v5 so am facing version issues. The same environment is working fine locally on Mac, but on live server (ubuntu 16.04) it's not.

Comment: Did you add your contract to the migrations file? If not `truffle migrate` will not deploy it.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify the folder structure:

[truffle's folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hjwu.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue is. I was deploying to a previous backup of geth blockchain, which is not possible in this case.

This has been solved by creating a fresh new blockchain directory and then deploying all the solidity files there.

What bothers here is why truffle doesnt log these issues. I hope they add more and more logging on the next release.